# Redirect inside the constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have a `Currency` cookie, it should be either `USD` or `GBP`. If someone manually change it to for example `RUB`, it will revert back to `USD`.

To achieve this, I created `BaseController` class to inherits `System.Web.MVC.Controller`, then every controller in my project will inherits `BaseController`, inside `BaseController` constructor I call `CheckcookieValidity()` method. Code below :

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
      public BaseController()
      {
           If (CheckCookieValidity() == false)
           {
                SetDefaultCookie();
           }
      }
}

public void SetDefaultCookies()
{
    var curr = new HttpCookie("curr");
    curr.Value = "USD";
    curr.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(2);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(curr);
}
```

I have some problem with this, if `SetDefaultCookie()` is called, the cookie doesn't change until the next page so

1. Is it possible to redirect/refresh page inside constructor?
2. Is this an acceptable way to check cookie validity? I know this question can be categorized as opinionated, but I need to know if there's a better way to achieve this.

Any help will be appreciated and apologize for bad english.

ANSWER :

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    if (CheckCookiesValidity() == false) {
        SetDefaultCookies();

        RouteValueDictionary route = new RouteValueDictionary(new {
            Controller = "Home",
            Action = "Index"
        });

        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(route);
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor may not be the best spot for this logic. I personally use the Initialize method to my custom AuthUser loading:

```
    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        // Custom code logic for every controller here
    }
```

Expanding on Tim's suggestion, an attribute may also be recommended. Something like this comes to mind:

```
public class CurrencyCheckAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        // Put your logic and potential redirect here.
    }
}
```

This can then be applied globally to all of your controllers as such:

```
[CurrencyCheck()]
public class BaseController : Controller
```

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if  its *possible* to redirect inside a Controller's constructor, but that certainly *seems* like a bad idea.

If you want to keep going the route of checking each request before the action, then you might want to look at custom Action Filters. There's a bunch of references to them on the web, but [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters) are a [couple](http://blog.falafel.com/custom-filter-asp-net-mvc-5/).

Comment: In my opinion, most the time doing intensive logic within the constructor is a bad idea.